# Hotmail/Outlook.com DKIM failure when signing with different domain - header.d ignored

Tags: dkim, email-server, email

We (sender.org) provide a mail server for a client (example.org) and sign outgoing messages with our private DKIM key (we cannot change the signing domain to the client's domain).

```
Return-Path: bounce@sender.org
From: from@example.org
```

The DKIM signature looks like this:

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; t=1413987605;
    s=default; d=sender.org;
    h=Reply-To:List-Unsubscribe:List-Id:From:To:Message-Id:Subject:Date:MIME-Version;
    bh=ISuMd/He7ct2h8gGuqNPS6u0Knk=;
    b=nLx/atDvwyl28uB6MSXRUoQO2tH0Dr46wn+IPnxioKMGBHlKFAeEArz0VZyvXIIG
    wM35CG8QspFTsRxvbV3Wfqx1+cR+6RIK1ecILXxCegNd3SCcaMao3fJ5IYAbL4yLiHy
    lbDvXPCSLmJ2uYsNG2ZeIkWDLLOG+WUjyzdtEPD8=
```

Gmail, Yahoo and others validate the DKIM signature correctly. However in Microsoft mail services such as Outlook.com or hotmail.com the DKIM validation fails:

```
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=pass (sender IP is 123.456.78.90) 
smtp.mailfrom=bounce@sender.org; dkim=none header.d=example.org; 
x-hmca=none header.id=from@example.org
```

The message says `dkim=none` even though the DKIM signature is in the header of the email. More importantly, the `header.d` is wrongly set to `example.org` whereas it should be `sender.org` - the domain that is signing.

We have tried to add `i=@sender.org` to the DKIM signature and changed the order of the header fields - nothing helped.

**Are we missing something?

Is this a bug in hotmail/Outlook.com?

Is there any solution or other indications on how to solve this?**

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug. Its a requirement from Microsoft.

Your emails must have a [Author Domain Signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Author_Domain_Signing_Practices#Author_Domain_Signature). In other words, domain name of the DKIM signing entity(d=), is the same as the domain name in the author address.

Your author address is from@example.org and signing entity is sender.org